# Display drivers have stopped responding

Tags: graphics-card, 64-bit, amd-radeon, dell-inspiron, amd-catalyst

When I try to open Catalyst Control Center of AMD 8730 (Model Dell Inspiron 15R 5521) this message appears:

> Catalyst Control Center cannot be started. There are currently no
>   settings that can be configured using Catalyst Control Center.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the tips (newer drivers, higher TdrDelay value or reducing the visual effects) from this KB article and look if something helps.

**"Display driver stopped responding and has recovered" error**

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2665946/en-us